# Meshing IEnumerable<T> Lists Together

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for the most efficient way to mesh all the rows in `IEnumerable<T> A` before each row in `IEnumerable<T> B`.

> For example:
>
> A = {A, B}
>
> B = {1, 2, 3}
>
> After meshing:
>
> B = {A, 1, B, 2, A, 3}

Comment: So you want to wrap around to the beginning when a shorter list is finished before a longer one? [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Interleave.cs) has an `Interleave` operation that almost achieves this. It wouldn't be too difficult to add a new `ImbalancedInterleaveStrategy` that states to wrap around to the start of the shorter list again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no easy solution, but something like this might work. The modulus operator is very important here, to repeat the results from the list with less items.

```
public static List<object> Mesh<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> s1, IEnumerable<T2> s2)
{
     T1[] array1 = s1.ToArray();
     T2[] array2 = s2.ToArray();
     int length1 = array1.Length;
     int length2 = array2.Length;
     int maxLength = Math.Max(length1, length2);
     List<object> result = new List<object>();
     for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
     {
          result.Add(array1[i % length1]);
          result.Add(array2[i % length2]);
     }
     return result.
}
```

Comment: Thats actually the only right solution, but you could put `Math.Max` outside of the loop.

Comment: @SebastianStehle very nice solution. Possibly I whould make it as extension and with only one type T

Comment: boxing tastic, My new answer (yes the old one sucked) does it without allocating arrays for the sequneces, returns an `IEnumerable` and will mesh any number of jagged sequences, @COBOL.

Answer (score 2):

That solution uses IEnumerable parameters directly without initializing them and also returns an IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<object> Mesh<S,T>(IEnumerable<S> items1, IEnumerable<T> items2){
    bool items1Empty;
    bool items2Empty;
    bool items1Finished = items1Empty = ValidateParameter(items1, "items1");
    bool items2Finished = items2Empty = ValidateParameter(items2, "items2");

    using(var items1Enumerator = items1.GetEnumerator()){
        using(var items2Enumerator = items2.GetEnumerator()){
            while(true){
                MoveNext(items1Enumerator, ref items1Finished);
                MoveNext(items2Enumerator, ref items2Finished);

                if(items1Finished && items2Finished)
                    break;

                if(!items1Empty)
                    yield return items1Enumerator.Current;

                if(!items2Empty)
                    yield return items2Enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}

private bool ValidateParameter<T>(IEnumerable<T> parameter, string parameterName){
    if(parameter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
    return !parameter.Any();
}

private void MoveNext(IEnumerator enumerator, ref bool finished){
    if(!enumerator.MoveNext()){
        enumerator.Reset();
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: A solution such as this is the answer since the question was "the most efficient". Any solution containing a ToArray/ToList call should probably not qualify.

Comment: I cleaned up code a little bit and corrected some faulty behavior that might have been occured.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, my first guess

```
for(int countA = 0, countB = 0; countA < A.Length; countA ++, countB++)
{
    if(countB >= B.Length)
    {
        countB = 0;
    }

    newList.Add(A[countA]);
    newList.Add(B[countB]);
}
```

Comment: That's not quite there, in the OP the A list is shorter, so this won't generate the required output.

Comment: But the pattern is right, I'm not going to do ALL the work for OP

Comment: I cannot access the Length property on an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Length for array Count for Enumerable

Answer (score 0):

I want to take a party too! Since I like LINQ very much, let's consider the following LINQ solution (sure it is not that efficient, but for fun):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var a = new[] {1, 2, 3};
    var b = new[] {'a', 'b'};

    var joined = a.Join(
        b, 
        x => Array.IndexOf(a, x) % b.Length, 
        y => Array.IndexOf(b, y) % a.Length, 
        (x, y) => new object[]{ x, y }
    );

    var flat = joined.SelectMany(x => x);

    Console.Write(string.Join(", ", flat));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Mesh<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params IEnumerable<T>[] others)
{
    var enumerators = new[] { source.GetEnumerator() }.Concat(others.Select(o => o.GetEnumerator())).ToList();

    var finishes = new bool[enumerators.Count];
    var allFinished = false;
    while (!allFinished)
    {
         allFinsihed = true;
         for (var i = 0; i < enumerators.Count; i++)
         {
             IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerators[i];
             if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
             {
                 finishes[i] = true;
                 enumerator.Reset();
                 enumerator.MoveNext(); // Not sure, if we need it here, Reset says: BEFORE the first element
             }

             yield return enumerator.Current;
             if (!finishes[i])
             {
                allFinished = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: That looks like copy-paste of Jodrell answer with little changes (reset of enumerator). Shame on you

Comment: I think the additional `MoveNext()` is a bad idea. Thats not what I'd expect when I call `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: This will procude something like { 1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 4, 'A', 5, 'B', 1, 'C' }. So it is repeating once to often.

Answer (score 0):

You could write you own extension to allow greater flexibility.

**Note: that this answer doesn't allocate a lot of unnecessary memory and enumerates all sequences exactly once.**

I've included parameter checking.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Mesh<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    params IEnumerable<T>[] others)
{
    if (others.LongLength == 0L)
    {
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            yield return t;
        }

        yield break;
    }

    var nullCheck = Array.FindIndex(others, e => e == null);
    if (nullCheck >= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format(
            "Parameter {0} is null, this is not supported.",
            ++nullCheck),
            (Exception)null);
    }

    var enumerators = new[] { source.GetEnumerator() }
        .Concat(others.Select(o => o.GetEnumerator())).ToList();

    try
    {
        var finishes = new bool[enumerators.Count];
        var allFinished = false;
        while (!allFinished)
        {
            allFinsihed = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < enumerators.Count; i++)
            {
                if (finishes[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (enumerators[i].MoveNext())
                {
                        yield return enumerators[i].Current;
                        allFinished = false;
                        continue;
                }

                finishes[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
        {
            enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }   
}
```

This would allow you to "Mesh" any number of jagged sequences as long has the items have the same type. e.g.

```
var a = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
var b = new[] { '1', '2', '3' };
var c = new[] { 'x', 'y' };
var d = new[] { '7', '8', '9', '0' };

var meshed = a.Mesh(b, c, d);
```

would yield

```
{ 'a', '1', 'x', '7', 'b', '2', 'y', '8', 'c', '3', '9', '0' }
```

---

If you wanted to mix types you could do

```
var a = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
var b = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var meshed = a.Cast<object>().Mesh(b.Cast<object>);
```

yielding something like,

```
{ ('a'), (1), ('b'), (2), ('c'), (3) }
```

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, not all enumerators support `Reset()`, I have ensured that all those I create are disposed.

Comment: After correcting compile time errors that will produce {1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 4, 5}. So it is not recurring like expected.

Comment: @woni, I found one compile error and fixed it. What test did you perform to get your unexpected result?

Comment: @woni, If I do `(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }).Cast<object>().Mesh((new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' }).Cast<object>())` I get exactly the sequence I'm expecting.

Comment: now I could follow you. I think the original question was to wrap the collections until all reached the end. So your example from above should output {a, 1, x, 7, b, 2, y, 8, c, 3, x, 9, a, 1, y, 0}. The result from your comment example should therefore be {1, A, 2, B, 3, C, 4, A, 5, B}.

Comment: @woni, you are correct I don't wrap the shorter sequences, I didn't get that from the original question and don't feel that it is implied by the term "Meshing". I suspect the OP only considered sequences of equal length.